# How can I append an interative value from my loop on to a string?

Tags: vbscript

I cannot figure out how to take the value from my loop iteration each time through (for example a = 1 to 100), and append it on to a string that is used for a command that will be executed each iteration.

An example of what I am trying to do is as follows so that I can make it a little more clear if my above explanation is somewhat confusing.  Some pseudo code as I am not fully familiar with the VB code syntax:

```
For a=1 to 100

**variable** = "M"+CStr(a);

workspace.Designs.Sch1.PartList.**variable**.ParamSet.RAD.Set(4);

Next
```

So the first time through the variable would be M1, then M2, M3, M4, so forth all the way to M100.  If anything is not clear please feel free to ask and I will gladly explain.

Comment: `For a=1 to 100:var = "M" & a:workspace.Designs.Sch1.PartList.var.ParamSet.RAD.Set(4):Next` isthe code you aretrying to write but won't work as your variable is part of a command. Are you sure about this? If so, and it seems wierd, you'll need to execute your command with eval function. See Help.

Comment: See my answer.  The only thing I'm not clear about is where your command resides that you're executing every time.  Is it also something available within the VBScript scope?  Or is it external (command line, e.g.)?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a _string_ as a placeholder for a object/variable name, which you cannot do. `M1` is a property/object of `PartList` but you're trying to use the _string_ "M1" instead. Does `PartList` have a collection/`Item` property that allows you to specify a specific item by name/string?

Comment: Bond, that is exactly what I think is happening.  I am trying to pass a string into that spot and that is why I believe it is not working.  The error I receive is *Object doesn’t support this property or method.*  For your question, "Does PartList have a collection/Item property that allows you to specify a specific item by name/string?",  this is what I need to figure out.  Thank you for leading me in the right direction I appreciate it very much. It looks like this should be possible using CallByName, but I haven’t figured out the correct syntax.

Comment: `CallByName` is a VB function but it doesn't exist in VBScript. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you can't use a string in place of an object/variable name. You could try using the `Execute()` function, which is similar to `eval()` found in other languages like JavaScript. `Execute()` takes a string expression and executes it as if it were one or more VBScript statements.

```
For a = 1 To 100
    strCommand = "workspace.Designs.Sch1.PartList.M" & a & ".ParamSet.RAD.Set 4"
    Execute strCommand
Next
```

Side note: I removed your semicolon. VBScript doesn't use them as line-enders. I also removed the parens around `4`. They're also not needed here.

Comment: please consider to replace "VBScript expression" with "VBScript statement".

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Actually, it is an expression. And that expression can contain one or more statements.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you!  The 4 will also be a different value each time because the Radius for each command execution will be set to a different value but now that I see how to set the command up like this I can just insert the value similar to how you inserted a into the command.  Again thanks a lot I've been messing with this issue for a little while now with no luck so this is awesome!

Comment: @Bond - no, an expression evaluates to a value (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_%28computer_science%29), a statement executes/specifies an action (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28computer_science%29). If you try to Execute the expression "1+1", VBScript will complain: Error 1024 Expected statement.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I'll concede. :) I've updated the answer and used the description from the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim a
Dim output

For a = 1 To 100
    If (Len(output) > 0) Then output = output & ", "
    output = output & "M" & a
    'execute your command here.
Next
```

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do there.  I believe my problem comes not with actually forming the variable but when I attempt to pass output into the function call.  So if I would try workspace.Designs.Sch1.PartList.output.ParamSet.RAD.Set(4), it doesn't like output, and it doesn't get passed correctly so my command doesn't work:(

Comment: So what are you trying to pass to your function call?  The string in place of the `4` you currently have there?

Comment: Thank you also roryap for your help and input!